# Color narrow range bars?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I know how to color code and more, but Im kinda stuck on how to define the code.

I want to color code whenever there are two-three narrow candles in a row (volatility contraction) how would I define that?

Putting an absolute value would not be optimal (example 0.4%<) because that would differ between a stock with higher and lower range, also dependant on timeframe.

What is the simplest way to mark out 2-3 narrow candles ina row, that would work independent on timeframe/stock inherent range.

[image]

Ive thought about identifying the range of last 20 bars and then this to be within, but does not make sense.

Comment: Example image is missing

Comment: yes, Its added now!

Answer (score -1):

To detect a contraction in the volatility, you can use :

```
plot(ta.atr(5))
```

Plot this value on a distinct chart (overlay=false), you will see how it react when the volatility is lower or bigger.

Then you will be able to decide when the price is contracting or not.

To color a candle, use :

```
barcolor(color, offset, editable, show_last, title, display)
```